# /app/bootstrap.php.cache points to older vendor folder

Tags: symfony, deployment, capifony

please help me with this, I am driving crazy.

I have a problem with deployment of a Symfont 2.2 project.

Since I have a missing repository in my composer.json file, I made a depoly with capifony semi-automatic: I run deploy, and when he asks me for install dependencies, I say NO. Then, I MANUALLY copy the vendor folder from the previous release of my project, and then run assetic, clear cache and finally change symlink from current to my last release.

Everything worked fine until now: the app stop worked. The error is that the file /app/bootstrap.php.cache points the OLDER vendor folder, that is no more existing.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

M :)

Comment: this is from my log file: 
2015/12/02 14:35:54 [error] 4663#0: *567 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/mnt/www/commercialista/releases/20151102103417/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ClassCollectionLoader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /mnt/www/commercialista/releases/20151202104236/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 749
.......

Comment: what you mean by having a missing repository ? what happens if you manually delete the cached ClassLoader files ?

Comment: In my composer.json, there is a repository that has been deleted few days ago.
Where are located the ClassLoader files that you mentioned?

Comment: if you did not change the cache dir `rm -rf app/cache/*`

Comment: you should put the missing repo out of the vendor folder and put it under your own version control, so composer still works as supposed

Comment: I tried with rm -rf app/cache/* , but no effect occurs.
John, could you give me instructions on how to put the missing repo under my own version control? ... thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved in this manner:

I have commented out these two lines in my app.php:

```
//$loader = new ApcClassLoader(SITE, $loader);
//$loader->register(true);
```

and finally run

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
```

Hope this helps.

Any further help would be welcome :)